# Native Windows: How to capture windows that are covered by other windows like Google Hangouts does

Tags: windows, api, window, native, capture

I'm working on a feature that allows users to capture windows and stream them. Using native windows api calls, I'm able to get a windows location and capture it.

BUT, if there is a window over it... I'm not able to capture that blocked portion and I just replace that area with gray.

SOMEHOW... google chrome, a non-microsoft app... figured out how to capture a window while it's behind other windows. Skype for Business, a Microsoft product, can't even do that.

Has anyone worked on something like this before? If so, a point in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!